# Diferencia entre window.screen.availHeight y window.innerHeight

Tags: javascript

Pensé que devolvía el tamaño máximo que podia tener el **viewport**, pero al asignarle al `height` de un elemento el valor de `window.screen.availHeight` es incluso mas grande que el `viewport` en cuanto al alto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Propiedad `innerHeight`**

- Esta obtiene la cantidad de pixeles que de forma vertical tiene **disponibles** en *viewport* que es el espacio visible de tu navegador web (pero que no representa necesariamente el 100% del espacio disponible que la página web tiene para mostrar todos sus elementos)

**Ejemplo**

Si con el navegador a pantalla completa ejecuto:

```
window.innerHeight
```

Obtengo **624**

Que representan los pixeles verticales que posee el viewport

En cambio si redimensiono y dejo a la *mitad* mi navegador de forma vertical obtendré: **312** que serán ahora pos pixeles disponibles que tiene el *viewport* para mostrar el contenido de la página web

**Propiedad `availHeight`**

- Esta obtiene el tamaño total en pixeles que posee la pantalla en dirección vertical, no importa si redimensionas el navegador la medida será una y no cambiará.

**Ejemplo**

```js
    let altoTotal = window.screen.availHeight
    let anchoTotal = window.screen.availWidth
    
    console.log(`Tu pantalla mide de alto: ${altoTotal} y de ancho ${anchoTotal}`)
```

Que en mi caso particular da como resultado:

> "Tu pantalla mide de alto: 724 y de ancho 1366"

**Referencias**

- [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/M%C3%B3vil/Viewport_meta_tag)
- [innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight)
- [availHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Screen/availHeight)